# How to correctly use CDI in @Asynchronous method?

Tags: jsf, asynchronous, ejb, cdi

I have a JSF 2 application (running on top of JBoss AS 7.1) that has to start a long process when the user clicks a button in a page. The idea is to have a not blocking interaction, so the user can wait and see the results or simply close the page and get back later to see how it is going or the results, if the process is concluded already.

The process itself is coded in a following (simplified) class:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyProcessManager {
    @Inject
    private ProcessHelper processHelper;

    @Asynchronous
    public void start(final ProcessParameters parameters) {
        // the process...
    }
}
```

Such a class is marked as `@ApplicationScoped` because all the processes running (for all the users) are kept by it. So, when the button is clicked, the backing bean sets some parameters and calls the asynchronous method `start()`.

Everything goes ok until the moment the process tries to use `processHelper`, which runs a number of Hibernate queries in order to proceed with the persistence part of the process. When the first method of `processHelper` is called I get the follwing exception:

```
WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
```

As an additional info, a breakpoint inside of such a method is never hit.

What is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception suggests that `ProcessHelper` is `@RequestScoped`.

When `@Asynchronous` is invoked, a brand new and separate thread is spawned which is **not** controlled by the HTTP servlet container. In the context of that thread, there's thus no means of a HTTP request or HTTP session anywhere. You can only use `@ApplicationScoped`, not `@RequestScoped`, let alone `@SessionScoped`.

As to the `ProcessManager` itself, the combination `@Stateless @ApplicationScoped` doesn't make sense. You most probably actually want a [`@javax.ejb.Singleton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html). Additional bonus is that it's stateful, so you could just keep the process results there as an instance variable.

You mentioned that `ProcessHelper` in turn runs some DB queries. Which means that it should run in transaction. In that case you should make it a fullworthy EJB instead of a CDI managed bean. So make `ProcessHelper` a `@Stateless` too, or just move all the DB interaction job into the `ProcessManager` EJB. That's also possible.

So, all in all, this should do it:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Start" action="#{processBacking.start}" />
</h:form>
<p>
    Result (manually refresh page to check): #{processBacking.result}
</p>
```

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ProcessBacking {

    @Inject
    private ProcessManager processManager;

    public void start() {
        // ...
        processManager.start(parameters);
    }

    public ProcessResult getResult() {
        return processManager.getResult();
    }

    // ...
}
```

```
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
public class ProcessManager {

    private ProcessResult result;

    @Inject
    private ProcessHelper helper;

    @Asynchronous
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public void start(ProcessParameters parameters) {
        ProcessResult result = runSomeLongRunningNonTransactionalProcess(parameters);
        this.result = helper.persist(result);
    }

    public ProcessResult getResult() {
        return result;
    }

}
```

```
@Stateless
public class ProcessHelper {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public ProcessResult persist(ProcessResult result) {
        entityManager.persist(result);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Do note that a `@Singleton` is by default read/write locked. So you can't invoke `getResult()` until the `start()` is finished. Hence the `ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN`, which means that it's unlocked and thus essentially the caller is itself responsible for concurrency management. This allows you to keep refreshing the page as long as the process still runs.

#### See also:

- [Is it safe to start a new thread in a JSF managed bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149919/is-it-safe-to-start-a-new-thread-in-a-jsf-managed-bean)

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for a solution for this but couldn't quite find a definite answer. But it may be useful somehow for you.

Apparently CDI does not propagate it's scope with asynchronous methods (actually it does not propagate the context to any other threads), and because of this when you try to `@Inject` a resource you receive an error. I couldn't find a proper documentation for this behavior, but I came across on at least a couple of questions with a problem very similar to yours:

[Java injection inside @Asynchronous bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888007/java-injection-inside-asynchronous-bean)

[Communicating between cdi session contexts — with database, will proper cdi context be invoked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812643/communicating-between-cdi-session-contexts-with-database-will-proper-cdi-con)

If we assume that this is in fact the current behavior of CDI, your best bet to solve this problem is to get rid of the `@Inject` and create a new instance of `ProcessHelper`, or maybe get rid of the `@Asynchronous` annotation and use a `ManagedExecutorService`, like suggested in the first question I have linked above.